# Group by in Power Pivot

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have a table sitting in power pivot that I need to group the data in. I have looked online and tried ten or so methods but for some reason this just isn't working despite this being the simplest table you could think of.

Basically I have a list of rooms that I need a distinct count of i.e. Room1, Room2, Room3. Essentially I just want a distinct count of all of the rooms in column. The data is over a year, so would tell me how many days the room has been used. There is also a days column, but probably don't even need to use that.

I can do this in excel, and power query but struggling in Power Pivot (excel data model).

Current formula is;
=GROUPBY('ROOM.TBL',[ROOMS],"ROOM UTILIZATION",[COUNT])

I have also tried using sum instead of count but this isn't working.

I know you can do this in many different ways, including summarize, but for what ever reason it is not working.

Any help or alternatives appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample file?

Comment: Same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53710730/what-is-proper-dax-groupby-syntax-in-calculated-column-in-power-pivot-in-excel-i